Can't connect to Jupyter lab of my Apache/Sedona container via localhost
I'm working on Fink ( an astro-physicist-big-data project). My job is to modify Apache:Sedona code in order to manage 3D data (either geometries and algorithms).
I use a remote server's VM based on Alpinelinux and my CPU is Ubuntu 22.04 and I'm obviously in bash.
My problem:
I can't found the jupyter lab by using the usual http://127.0.0.1:8888/lab
after running a docker run.
What I did:
I pulled Apache/Sedona docker:
docker pull apache/sedona
Run the command below:
docker run -e DRIVER_MEM=2g -e EXECUTOR_MEM=2g -p 8888:8888  apache/sedona:latest
knowing that original command (found in apache/sedona docker hub was designed for 8GB.
Or, when i run this and try to access to localhost: it never works.

JupyterLab localhost 8888 is not designed to be accessed from remote server, by default.
You will need to do extra config for JupyterLab. You might need to build the docker image yourself.
See: https://medium.com/@mlquest0/set-up-remote-jupyter-lab-notebook-server-for-remote-browser-access-2cef464f203e

Thx @Jya Yu
Finally, my problem was that i try to open a port from remote server to my cpu. Also, i didn't understood that i had to configure the port between my container and the remote server and also between remote server and my machine.There is more than one port to forward here. So i asked the admin of the remote server for opening a port from the VM to my machine
sudo docker run -p 23000:8888 apache/sedona
After that i opened my browser (Chrome) and type following adress (because bash proposed by default port 8888):
http://127.0.0.1:23000/lab
